# Notation on Schubert's Op.94, D760, piece 6

Tags: piano, notation

I was practicing the 6th moment musicaux of Schubert's Op. 94 using a Henle edition (which is in public domain in imslp, [Here](http://conquest.imslp.info/files/imglnks/usimg/e/ed/IMSLP38719-PMLP02066-Schubert-6Moments-Musicaux-D780-ed-Henle.pdf)) and I encountered something I have never seen before.

Over the bars 30, 32, 73, 109 you can see the numbers 1, 2, 3 and 4, respectively, inside a circle. I'm pretty sure they aren't fingering. What are they?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look in the back of the book and see if they are notes.  (Not the kind of notes you play.  The kind of notes that explain things.)  Usually the notes in Henle editions aren't indicated in the score; I haven't seen this before.

Comment: I, too, think they probably refer to comments at the beginning or end of the book. Some supporting evidence for this is that they occur in all the pieces, in order (except when the same number is used at identical places) and at seemingly semi-random places.

Comment: I've seen this in other scores for other instruments. Think of it like a footnote or endnote.

Comment: Yes, they are notes about some other editions printed, or about the way the editor plays some part. It's strange because henle has another way of doing that, not putting numbers on the score, but referencing them at the end. Thanks.